# Probability of a sum of variable

Tags: probability

I have two independently variables $x_1$ and $x_2$. $$P(x_i) = e^{-x_i}$$ I need to find the probabiltiy distribuition function of $y = (x_1 + x_2)$, but look:

$$P(y) = \int \int P(x_1) P(x_2) \delta (y-x_1-x_2) dx_1 dx_2= \int P(x_1) P(y-x_1)dx_1 = \int e^{-y} dx_1$$

And so it diverges!
What am i a doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a whole host of confusions going on here, and a lot of them can be traced back to poor notation.  The particular piece where things are going wrong is that you aren't paying attention to your limits of integration, but that isn't the only 'notational crime' being committed here.

To put it right: say that your two random variables are $X_1$ and $X_2$, and $Y:=X_1+X_2$.  Let $\rho_{X_1}, \rho_{X_2}, \rho_Y$ be the probability density functions for $X_1$, $X_2$, and $Y$ respectively. I'm assuming that by "$P(X_i)=e^{-x_i}$", what you *really* mean is
$$
\rho_{X_i}(x_i)=\begin{cases}e^{-x_i}, & x_i\geq 0\\ 0, & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}.
$$

Then for a fixed $y$,
$$
\begin{align*}
\rho_Y(y)&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\rho_{X_1}(x_1)\cdot\rho_{X_2}(y-x_1)\,dx_1.
\end{align*}
$$
Now, note that this integrand is $0$ whenever either $x_1<0$ or $y-x_1<0$; this it is only nonzero for $x_1\in[0,y]$. Thus
$$
\rho_Y(y)=\int_0^ye^{-x_1}\cdot e^{-(y-x_1)}\,d_{x_1}=\int_0^ye^{-y}\,dx_1=ye^{-y}.
$$

As an additional note: that original double formula you showed will not serve you well.  If computed correctly, that double integral will always be zero -- it represents the area of a curve!

Answer (score 0):

Your r.v.s $X_1$ and $X_2$ $\sim$ Exponential$(\lambda=1)$.

$Y=X_1+X_2$ has Gamma distribution. You can prove that easily using the MGF technique. As an exercise find the parameters for this Gamma.

Comment: While your answer is correct, it doesn't actually make any effort to address the confusion the OP expressed in the question.